# Why doesn't Inserting data from Json Object work?

Tags: php, mysql, json, object, pdo

I don't know why insert values in my table doesn't work using foreach to traverse Json Object.. when I see the table, fields are empty.

**Json Object (from jquery.ajax)**

```
[{"marca":"Cisco","producto":"UCS","subproducto":"Nexus"},"marca":"Citrix","producto":"Networking","subproducto":"Netscaler"}]
```

**print_r($data)**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [marca] => Cisco
        [producto] => UCS
        [subproducto] => Nexus
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [marca] => Citrix
        [producto] => Networking
        [subproducto] => Netscaler
    )

)
```

**PHP CODE**

```
$data = json_decode($this->dataNewPoliza['alcances'], true);

$marca;
$producto;
$subproducto;

$sqlAlc = "INSERT INTO t_poliza_alcanceproductos VALUES (:idp,:m,:p,:s)";
$resultAlc = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sqlAlc) or die ($sqlAlc);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $mps => $valuemps) {
            if($mps == 'marca') {
            $marca = $valuemps;
        }

        if($mps == 'producto') {
            $producto = $valuemps;
        }

        if($mps == 'subproducto') {
            $subproducto = $valuemps;
        }
    }

    $resultAlc->bindValue(':idp',$id_poliza,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':m',$marca,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':p',$producto,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':s',$subproducto,PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if(!$resultAlc->execute()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope to get some help.

**Solved**

The problem was that I could not do return false or true within the foreach and as said @zerkms , I don't need nested loop, and this is final result:

```
$data = json_decode($this->dataNewPoliza['alcances'], true);

$sqlAlc = "INSERT INTO t_poliza_alcanceproductos VALUES (:idp,:m,:p,:s)";

$resultAlc = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sqlAlc) or die ($sqlAlc);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':idp',$id_poliza,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':m',$value['marca'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':p',$value['producto'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultAlc->bindValue(':s',$value['subproducto'],PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $resultAlc->execute();
}

return true;
```

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Discover `$value['marca']`, what you do with nested loop is just nonsense

Comment: I agree with zerkms also is it normal that $id_poliza is not set in ur code (probably set before no?)

Comment: Could give me an example of how you could do better please? And yes, $id_poliza stated before that code.

Comment: @SoldierCorp: `$value['marca']` - this is how you access the array values

Comment: @zerkms Nested loop is necesary because Json has two arrays inside, then if I remove the second each, only insert one record in database (but with blank values yet). I print $value['marca'] , value['producto'] , value['subproducto'] before execute $result and if they have data but not insert.

Comment: @SoldierCorp: nested loop is pointless, you can access the array values with `$value['marca']` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDOStatement::bindValue data type wrong, $marca, $product, $subproducto is string not integer.

```
$resultAlc->bindValue(':m',$marca,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Maybe you should look [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: Yes, corrected that but now the loop runs only 1 time and only 1 array inserted in the table

Comment: after $resultAlc->execute print PDO::errorInfo Fetch extended error information associated with the last operation on the database handle

Comment: @SoldierCorp So what is your new question? If insert for failed you whether tried print PDO::errorInfo.